# Oracle 10g UTL_HTTP begin_request return ORA-29273: HTTP request failed

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I am using Oracle10g plsql to access a Jasperserver webservice in order to generate a PDF and store it in a blob. I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706770/procedure-to-download-file-from-a-given-url-in-oracle-11g-and-save-it-into-the-b)

When I change the Jasperserver host I replace the url from

```
http://myOLDserver:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/apex/reportname.pdf?j_username=jus&j_password=jpw&ID=2758
```

to

```
http://myNEWserver:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/apex/reportname.pdf?j_username=jus&j_password=jpw&ID=2758
```

and the procedure raise an error like this

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1389
ORA-29261: bad argument
ORA-06512: at line 51
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1029
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

on executing *UTL_HTTP.begin_request*

The machine of my oracle user ping myNEWserver correctly and the url in a browser is working correctly

Comment: So it worked on your old web server but not your new one?

Comment: @APC : sorry for the delay, but yes and I realize that the old server was the same of the db and the new is a different one. So the DBA that set up the jasper server and the new db miss some config I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem was an incorrect configuration of the DNS of my db server.

From different db server correctly configured the UTL_HTTP.begin_request with the same URL work without error with no db configuration like ACL or WALLET.

The db server that call the procedure is AIX Version 6.1 and I have to modify the /etc/resolv.conf and the hosts (because it is not possible to reboot the servere immediatly).

I hope this solution can help

Comment: @AlexMl dear I am facing the same issue, the diffrence between me and you is the not all request fail about 30% of them fail and the other succeed ... what would you advise